# Reposition FormView on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

On web page I display list of comments, I want to add an option to reply to any comment.
For this i would like to display a FormView (or DetailsView ) under the comment.

One options is to insert this hidden forview under every comment and display the needed one.

Is there a way to have only one formview and display it in needed place?
(if its important, comment are listed as list of `<ul></ul>` on the page )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using JavaScript for this particular problem. Using jQuery you could do something like this.

1. Render your formview in a div on the page, somewhere below the commentrepeater, let's assume the div's id is `reply` and has a `style="display: none"`.
2. When clicking the reply link, there should be an `onClientClick` action on the link, which calls `ShowReplyForm(this)`.
3. Some JavaScript function like

   ```
   function ShowReplyForm(sender) {
       $("#reply").remove().appendTo(sender).show(); 
   }
   ```

   *In normal JavaScript*

   ```
   function ShowReplyForm(sender) {
       var replyObj = document.getElementById("reply");
       replyObj.parentNode.removeChild(replyObj);
       sender.appendChild(replyObj);
       replyObj.style.display = "block";
   }
   ```